# What is the C# equivalent of document.getElementByClassName("mat-form-field-infix")[0]

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello everyone here is the thing, I need to confirm if an element is visible on the screen, the current code I'm using is:

```
WaitVisible(By.ClassName("mat-form-field-infix"));
```

but that element occurs three times and I need to be sure that I'm pointing at the right one, I found that using:

```
document.getElementByClassName("mat-form-field-infix")
```

adding `[0]` leads me to the specific element, but I don't know how to translate that to Selenium, any thoughts?

Comment: `I need to be sure that I'm pointing at the right one`: what constitutes the "right" one? If you have three elements with the `mat-form-field-infix` class, which one do you want?

Comment: I want to point to a specific (any)one at a time, not just letting the selenium automatically point to the first.

Answer (score 3):

you could use something like the below but without your html posted, I am kind of guessing. Is that class from a div, input, span? This allows you to set a custom wait time in your call using xpath. The call is set to 30 seconds.

call:

```
WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPathCustomTime("//div[@class='mat-form-field-infix'][0]", 30);
```

method:

```
   public static void WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPathCustomTime(string value, Int32 time)
    {
        try
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, time));
            wait.Until(webDriver => Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(value)).Displayed);
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably instead of `getElementByClassName()` it was [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp).

To use the *JavaScript*:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mat-form-field-infix")[0]
```

As a [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) command you can use:

```
var element = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.getElementsByClassName('mat-form-field-infix')[0]");
```